# typeerror with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I want to print a div using jspdf on a button click. My structure is as follow :

`html to print`

```
<div id="print">
Blah Blah

----

---
Blah Blah
</div>
```

`Button`

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Save As PDF !!!" onclick="save_this();">
```

`script`

```
<script>
function save_this()
{
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter')
    , source = jQuery('#print')[0]
    , specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){      
            return true
        }
    }

    margins = {
        top: 60,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
      };
      // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
      // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
        source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        , margins.left // x coord
        , margins.top // y coord
        , {
            'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
            , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },
        function (dispose) {
          // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
          //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            pdf.save('Downloaded.pdf');
          },
        margins
)
}
</script>
```

But When I am running this code I am getting error in console

```
TypeError: headers[j] is undefined
```

How can I resolve this error ???

Comment: Hello, Did you solve this TypeError. I also am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
1. use jsPDF AutoTable plugin v2.3.2 
2. Add important three js file as follwing  
 a.jquery-1.11.3.min.js  
 b.jspdf.debug.js
 c.jspdf.plugin.autotable.js 
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <script src="libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <div id="print">
            Blah Blah

            ----

            ---
            Blah Blah
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Save As PDF !!!" onclick="save_this();">
    </body>
    <script src="libs/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
    <script>
            function save_this()
            {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter')
                        , source = jQuery('#print')[0]
                        , specialElementHandlers = {
                            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                                return true
                            }
                        }

                margins = {
                    top: 60,
                    bottom: 60,
                    left: 40,
                    width: 522
                };
                // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
                // 'inches' in this case
                pdf.fromHTML(
                        source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                        , margins.left // x coord
                        , margins.top // y coord
                        , {
                            'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
                            , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                        },
                        function (dispose) {
                            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
                            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                            pdf.save('Downloaded.pdf');
                        },
                        margins
                        )
            }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Any chance of an explanation?